# Elasticsearch multi fields multi words match

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete, elasticsearch-query

I'm looking to implement an auto-complete like feature on my app with elasticsearch.

Let's say my input is `"ronan f"`, I want elastic to return all elements where `"ronan"` or `"f"` is contained in last name or first name. I expect elasticsearch to sort the result by rank, so the element which is the closest to what I search should be on top.

I tried multiple requests but none of them results as expected.

For example :

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
        "must_not": [
            {
                "match": {
                    "email": "*@guest.booking.com"
                }
            }
        ],
        "should": [
            {
                "match": {
                    "lastname": "ronan"
                }
            },
            {
                "match": {
                    "firstname": "ronan"
                }
            },
            {
                "match": {
                    "lastname": "f"
                }
            },
            {
                "match": {
                    "firstname": "f"
                }
            }
        ],
        "minimum_should_match" : 1
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    "_score"
  ],
  "from": 0,
  "size": 30
}
```

With this request the ranks seams a bit odds, for example :

```
"_index": "clients",
"_type": "client",
"_id": "4369",
"_score": 20.680058,
"_source": {
   "firstname": "F",
   "lastname": "F"
 }
```

is on top of :

```
"_index": "clients",
"_type": "client",
"_id": "212360",
_score": 9.230003,
"_source": {
   "firstname": "Ronan",
   "lastname": "Fily"
}
```

For me the second result should have a better rank than the first.

Can someone show me how can I achieve the result I want ?

For info, I can't use Completion Suggester functionality of elasticsearch because I can't access the configuration of the database (so no indexes).

Comment: Can you reindex your data if we share a analyser?

Comment: Yes probably. If I understand correctly, elasticsearch offer the possibility to create multiple analyser, which can be passed as argument to the query,  and each analyser can affect the result of the query. Sorry it's like my first 2 days with elasticsearch, I need to find some learning tutorials.

Comment: @toto1911, were u able to resolve the issue? or still looking for answer?

Comment: Yes I manage to optimize my reequest without using a new analyzer, I will close the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok as you can reindex your data i join a "start with" anylyzer. It will work caseless & on text field (i thinck first name and last name can have multi words on it).

Delete / create a new index using mappings.

define your analyzer (PUT my_index)
{
  "settings": {:

```
"filter": {
        "name_ngrams": {
            "max_gram": "20",
            "type": "edgeNGram",
            "min_gram": "1",
            "side": "front"
        }
    },
    "analyzer": {
        "partial_name": {
            "type": "custom",
            "filter": [
                "lowercase"
                ,
                "name_ngrams"
                ,
                "standard"
                ,
                "asciifolding"
            ],
            "tokenizer": "standard"
        },
        "full_name": {
            "type": "custom",
            "filter": [
                "standard"
                ,
                "lowercase"
                ,
                "asciifolding"
            ],
            "tokenizer": "standard"
        }
    }
```

post _mappings using this for your fields:

```
"lastname": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "partial_name",
        "search_analyzer": "full_name"

},

    "firstname": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "partial_name",
        "search_analyzer": "full_name"
}
```

if this is not clear and elasticsearch documentation couldnot help you dont hesite to ask us.